# Post GPU scaling colouring in OpenGL without shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I am writing a program to plot the distribution of a stream of live noisy data. The plots look something like

[image]

The scene is lit with 3 lights - 2 diffuse and 1 ambient - to allow modeling to be revealed once filtering is applied to the data

[image]

Currently vertical scaling and vertex colour assignment is done by my code before sending the vertices to the GPU using:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(c_vertex), &(vertex_store[0][0].x));
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(c_vertex),&(vertex_store[0][0].r));
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(c_vertex),&(vertex_store[0][0].nx));
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (max_bins-1)*(max_bins-1)*2*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, vertex_order);
```

The use of older functions is so that I can let the fixed pipeline do the lighting calculations with out me writing a shader [something I have not done to the depth needed to do lighting with 3 sources]

To speed up processing I would like to send unscaled data to the GPU and apply a matrix with X and Z scale of 1 and Y scale of the appropriate value to make the peaks reach to +1 on the y axis. After this I would then like the GPU to select the colour for the vertex depending on its post scaling Y value from a look-up table which I assume would be a texture map.

Now I know I can do the last paragraph IF I write my own shaders - but that the necessitates writing code for lighting which I want to avoid doing. Is there anyway of doing this using the buffers in the drawing code above?

Comment: If you don't want to do that using shaders, you can have a color array, change the color for each vertex depending on certain criteria and pass it to the GPU.

Comment: It is both possible and would be tremendously overcomplicated. The shader for simple per-vertex lighting is about 5 lines of GLSL code and can be found in various places over the Internet. Sooner or later you'll want to add more changes, and it will just get increasingly harder with fixed pipeline.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks for that - the problem I have yet to find a simple solution for is that I have 3 light sources to deal with and the code examples I have seen do not seem to use the vertex colour - that said I want to use a 1d texture map to carry the vertex-y related rgb colour value

Comment: @concept3d that is what I do already - i scale the data in the y axis to a value between 0 and 1 then use that value as the index for a lookup table where I have stored the RGB map. The RGB value is extracted from this look up table per vertex and stored in the colour buffer which is sent to the GPU with the ghDrawElements command

Comment: @user3591811 Ok, I don't really get the actual question, you tried fixed pipeline, and you don't want to use shaders. can you please clarify your actual question?

Comment: @user3591811 Adding that is trivial, though, be it trough 1D color map or as another vertex attribute. `ColorPointer` and friends have been superseeded by the functions that are *more powerful*.

Comment: @concept3d basically yes - got render of scene illuminated with 3 sources without using shaders, but now I have the problem that I want to move the scaling and the vertex colour setting to the GPU to free up CPU - but using shaders to do scaling necessitates shaders doing lighting - and shader based normal caculation, both of which are not something I've done before

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz just realised that if I scale in the shader, not only do I have to calculate lighting for 3 sources but also have to calculate normals in the shader :( yes - I know there is code out there to do bits of this - but it is not something I have any experience of hence looking for easier solution

Comment: Why would you have to calculate normals in the shader? They shouldn't change with scale. Or rather, could be scaled the same way as vertices and renormalized?

Answer (score 0):

> After
>   this I would then like the GPU to select the colour for the vertex
>   depending on its post scaling Y value from a look-up table which I
>   assume would be a texture map.

You *really* should write your own shaders for that. Writing a shader for 3 light sources isn't more complicated as writing one for just one and making a loop around it.

However, I think what you asked for could still be done with the fixed function pipeline. You can use a 1D texture for the colors, enable texturing and the *automatic texture coordinate generation*, the latter via the [`glTexGen()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexGen.xml) family of functions.

In your specific case, the best appraoch seems to set up a `GL_OBJECT_LINEAR` mapping for `s` (the first and only texture coordinate that you would need for a 1D texture):

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
```

What the GL now will do is calcualte `s` as a function of your input vertex cooridnates (x,y,z,w) such that:

```
s=a*x + b*y + c*z + d*w
```

where `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are just some coefficients you can freely choose. I'm assuming your original vertices just need to be scaled along y direction by a scaling factor `V`, so you can just set `b=V` and all other to zero:

```
GLfloat coeffs[4]={0.0f, V, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_OBJECT_PLANE, coeffs);
```

Then, you just have to enable texture mapping and provide a texture to get the desired lookat.